# Como validar campos nulos e/ou vazios ao criar objetos em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, validação

Tenho um objeto e gostaria de forçar o preenchimento dos atributos no momento da criação do objeto. Qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Existem as anotações `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty` e `@NotBlank` do Hibernate, mas não se encaixa no cenário aqui. Atualmente estou utilizando um método para validar antes do objeto ser utilizado em outra classe, segue abaixo exemplo:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class User {

    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public User(String usuario, String senha) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        return (Objects.nonNull(usuario) && Objects.nonNull(senha)) && (!usuario.isEmpty() && !senha.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Por exemplo, essa validação pode ser feita no construtor e nos métodos `set` evitando-se assim um método para validar?

Comment: Li por cima, mas `this.usuario = Objects.requireNonNull(usuario);` não te atenderia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou até na dúvida se a dúvida é essa mesmo, porque me pareceu simples demais (se for isso eu completo a resposta, senão eu apago):

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    User usuario = new User("joao", "123");
    System.out.println(usuario);
  }
}

class User {
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public User(String usuario, String senha) {
        setUsuario(usuario);
        setSenha(senha);
    }
    public String getUsuario() { return usuario; }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        if (usuario == null || usuario.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("usuário esstá inválido");
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public String getSenha() { return senha; }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        if (usuario == null || usuario.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("usuário esstá inválido");
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/egbrJd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ValidationSpecific). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ValidationOnSetter.java).

Eu acho ruim lançar exceção para isto, mas é a forma como se costuma fazer em Java (já vi alguns programadores Java fazendo diferente, então há esperanças, mas duvido que se torne o padrão).

Comment: por curiosidade, por que você acha ruim esta abordagem?

Comment: Acredito que lançar exceção ou não vai depender da sua regra de negócio. Se for um dado crucial onde sem ele o sistema não funciona, por exemplo, faz sentido lançar uma exceção.

Comment: @nullptr procure tudo o que eu falo sobre exceção no site. Respondendo aos dois, exceção não deveria ser regra de negócio, exceção é algo excepcional, se é algo que você sabe que é normal acontecer não é exceção. Esse código não deixa criar o objeto se for invbálido, você testou? Eu testei: https://repl.it/@maniero/ValidationSpecific.

Comment: @Maniero, é que neste caso eu acharia interessante mencionar um outro formato de validação como opção. Questiono porque já vi várias implementações utilizando este método, e várias outras não utilizando (utilizando serviços para validação, gerando outros problemas como os devs esquecerem de chamar para validar), utilizando validação por libs (hibernate-validator por exemplo). Vejo que todas as abordagens possuem prós e contras e inclusive estou buscando montar um artigo com comparativos sobre, visto que todas elas podem acontecer em momentos distintos dentro de uma aplicação.

Comment: @nullptr não nesta pergunta que não pede isso, mas uma das minhas respostas mais votadas fala de métodos alternativos

Answer (score 1):

Eu também não sou muito fã de jogar exceção, como falado pelo @Maniero, pois isso será lançado em tempo de execução e não faria diferença alguma em relação a verificação de null.

Ao invés de lançar exceção, use `import org.springframework.lang.NonNull; @NonNull`  na variável. Isso mostrará ao desenvolvedor que existe a possibilidade de estar criando um objeto com variável null.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

lombok `import lombok.NonNull;` também tem anotação para isso (nunca testei).

De qualquer forma, tu tens opções de fazer a validação (resposta do @Maniero) sem lançar exceção.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-null-safety-annotations

https://www.baeldung.com/java-avoid-null-check